# How do I get embeddings from Huggingface(in sagemaker) instead of features?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, huggingface-transformers, sentence-transformers

I have a text classifier model that depends on embeddings from a certain huggingface model

```py
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model = SentenceTransformer('T-Systems-onsite/cross-en-de-roberta-sentence-transformer')
encodings = model.encode("guckst du bundesliga")
```

this has a shape of (768,)

tldr: is there a clean simple way to do this on sagemaker (hopefully using the images it provides) ?

context:
looking at docs of this [huggingface model](https://huggingface.co/T-Systems-onsite/cross-en-de-roberta-sentence-transformer?text=guckst%20du%20bundesliga) the only sagemaker option I see is feature extraction

```py
from sagemaker.huggingface import HuggingFaceModel
import sagemaker

role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()
# Hub Model configuration. https://huggingface.co/models
hub = {
    'HF_MODEL_ID':'T-Systems-onsite/cross-en-de-roberta-sentence-transformer',
    'HF_TASK':'feature-extraction'
}

# create Hugging Face Model Class
huggingface_model = HuggingFaceModel(
    transformers_version='4.6.1',
    pytorch_version='1.7.1',
    py_version='py36',
    env=hub,
    role=role, 
)

# deploy model to SageMaker Inference
predictor = huggingface_model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1, # number of instances
    instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge' # ec2 instance type
)

predictor.predict({
    'inputs': "Today is a sunny day and I'll get some ice cream."
})
```

this gives my the features which has a shape (9, 768)

there is a connection between these two values, which is seen from a another code sample

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
import torch


#Mean Pooling - Take attention mask into account for correct averaging
def embeddings(feature_envelope, attention_mask):
    features = feature_envelope[0] #First element of model_output contains all token embeddings
    input_mask_expanded = attention_mask.unsqueeze(-1).expand(features.size()).float()
    sum_embeddings = torch.sum(features * input_mask_expanded, 1)
    sum_mask = torch.clamp(input_mask_expanded.sum(1), min=1e-9)
    return sum_embeddings / sum_mask

#Sentences we want sentence embeddings for
sentences = ['guckst du bundesliga']

#Load AutoModel from huggingface model repository
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('T-Systems-onsite/cross-en-de-roberta-sentence-transformer')
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained('T-Systems-onsite/cross-en-de-roberta-sentence-transformer')

#Tokenize sentences
encoded_input = tokenizer(sentences, padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=128, return_tensors='pt')

#Compute token embeddings
with torch.no_grad():
    model_output = model(**encoded_input)
#     print(model_output)

#Perform pooling. In this case, mean pooling
sentence_embeddings = embeddings(model_output, encoded_input['attention_mask'])
sentence_embeddings.shape, sentence_embeddings
```

But as you can see cant derive embedding given only features

Answer (score 1):

You could look at defining your own "User defined code" by making use of an `inference.py` file.

https://huggingface.co/docs/sagemaker/inference#user-defined-code-and-modules

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this notebook titled [Sentence Embeddings with Hugging Face Transformers, Sentence Transformers and Amazon SageMaker - Custom Inference for creating document embeddings with Hugging Face's Transformers.](https://github.com/huggingface/notebooks/blob/main/sagemaker/17_custom_inference_script/sagemaker-notebook.ipynb)

It's a recipe for writing your own custom inference.py script.

I had difficulty getting this code to leverage GPU for faster inference on a `ml.g4dn.xlarge` instance. If you want to leverage GPU, try including the chunk of code under `# Update the inputs to be GPU compatible`

```
%%writefile code/inference.py

from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

# Helper: Mean Pooling - Take attention mask into account for correct averaging
def mean_pooling(model_output, attention_mask):
    token_embeddings = model_output[0] #First element of model_output contains all token embeddings
    input_mask_expanded = attention_mask.unsqueeze(-1).expand(token_embeddings.size()).float()
    return torch.sum(token_embeddings * input_mask_expanded, 1) / torch.clamp(input_mask_expanded.sum(1), min=1e-9)


def model_fn(model_dir):
  # Load model from HuggingFace Hub
  tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_dir)
  model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_dir)
  return model, tokenizer

def predict_fn(data, model_and_tokenizer):
    # destruct model and tokenizer
    model, tokenizer = model_and_tokenizer
    
    # Tokenize sentences
    sentences = data.pop("inputs", data)
    encoded_input = tokenizer(sentences, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors='pt')

    # Update the inputs to be GPU compatible
    device = "cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
    encoded_input = encoded_input.to(device)
    model = model.to(device)
    
    # Compute token embeddings
    with torch.no_grad():
        model_output = model(**encoded_input)

    # Perform pooling
    sentence_embeddings = mean_pooling(model_output, encoded_input['attention_mask'])

    # Normalize embeddings
    sentence_embeddings = F.normalize(sentence_embeddings, p=2, dim=1)
    
    # return dictonary, which will be json serializable
    return {"vectors": sentence_embeddings[0].tolist()}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a python or ML guy so take this with a grain of salt. I ran into the same question when deploying an inference endpoint. The below extracts the data I believe you're looking for.

```
sentence_embeddings = mean_pooling(model_output, encoded_input['attention_mask'])

cos = torch.nn.CosineSimilarity(dim=1, eps=1e-6)

all_sentence_combinations = []
for i in range(len(sentence_embeddings) - 1):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(sentence_embeddings)):
        opt = cos(sentence_embeddings[i].unsqueeze(0), sentence_embeddings[j].unsqueeze(0))
        all_sentence_combinations.append([opt.item(), i, j])

arr = []
for score, i, j in all_sentence_combinations:
    arr.append([sentences[i], sentences[j], score])
    print("{} \t {} \t {:.4f}".format(sentences[i], sentences[j], score))
```